# Is it pedagogically better to interpret 感兴趣 as two words: 感 ("feel") and 兴趣 ("interest")?

Tags: word

Now that I've taken the HSK6 exam, I'm looking into writing a kind of "graduate thesis", so I'm going through the HSK words filling in gaps in my knowledge.  Who knows, maybe one day I'll become a Chinese teacher.  With this in mind...

> [CC-CEDICT](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E6%84%9F%E5%85%B4%E8%B6%A3): 感兴趣 (gǎn​xìng​qù​) to be interested

This word is not in my dictionary, and I'm guessing that's because the dictionary considers it a collocation of two words:

> [CC-CEDICT](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E6%84%9F): 感 (gǎn​) to feel / to move / to touch / to affect / feeling / emotion / (suffix) sense of ~
> [CC-CEDICT](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E5%85%B4%E8%B6%A3): 兴趣 (​xìng​qù​) interest (desire to know about sth) / interest (thing in which one is interested) / hobby / CL: 個｜个

Thus, I'm wondering if it's better to interpret 感兴趣 as two words, or if there is some concrete reason (that I'm missing) why 感兴趣 is better interpreted as one word.

**Question**: Is it pedagogically better to interpret 感兴趣 as two words: 感 ("feel") and 兴趣 ("interest")?

<sub>(Just in case someone needs the definition: [*pedagogical*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pedagogical): of, relating to, or befitting a teacher or education.)</sub>

Comment: This is a phrase made up by v (感, feel) + adj (兴趣, interested). A similar phrase is 有 (have, v) + 兴趣 (interest, noun).

Comment: Yes, I think this is how I understand this word.

Comment: can't answer your question, but recall some memory when I was young. As a native speaker, I didn't learn a definition of "word" when I was in school. My concept was wrong: word=字, phrase=詞=兩字或以上. I had little concept about "word" and all my concept was about "character". It was until I've graduated from school when I realized "oh! I was wrong, should be 字=character, 詞=word"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

感兴趣 (feel interested) is functionally a compound word  for "be interested in"

Example:

对钓鱼[**感兴趣**]的人通常也爱远足 - People who are [**interested in**] fishing usually also enjoy hiking

我对钓鱼不[**感兴趣**] - I am not [**interested in**] fishing

*爱 (love) > 喜欢 (like) > 感兴趣 (be interested in)> 不介意 (don't mind)*

I say it is functionally a compound word and not a two words phrase because  the verb 感(feel) is usually followed by an adjective

[倍感][孤单] 、 [深感][厭惡] 、 [大感][兴奋]、 [微感][寒冷]

But 兴趣 is a noun. It is very common to see compound verbs made up of [v + n]

[驾车] is made up of [驾] + [车]

[唱歌]is made up of [唱] +[歌]

[感兴趣] is made up of [感] + [兴趣]

Answer (score 0):

> 兴趣 is a noun.

Seems to be saying:

> a verb plus an object noun is a noun.

If that is true,

感兴趣 is a noun

If that is not true, 兴趣 is not a noun.

Can you clarify? When is a noun not a noun?

兴：举办，发动：兴办。兴工。兴学。兴建。兴叹（发出感叹声，如“望洋兴兴”）。百废待兴。